# How to fetch record on the basis of @DBRef in collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Hi i am using mongodb with springboot and not able to fetch records on the basis of @DBRef. My scenerio is:

I have AuthenticationToken Collection and User collection as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556bdfc2ccf2e6509f8a2849"),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.user.AuthenticationToken",
    "token" : "2efd1cfe-2f2f-4163-b500-bac6e4654287",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-06-01T04:29:54.364Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-06-01T04:29:54.364Z"),
    "user" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("556bdfc2ccf2e6509f8a2848"))
}
```

And User

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556bdfc2ccf2e6509f8a2848"),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.user.User",
    "age" : 0,
    "username" : "abc@yahoo.com",
    "roles" : [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ],
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "mno",
    "email" : "abc@yahoo.com",
    "gender" : "male",
    "isAccountLocked" : false,
    "prefAgeFrom" : 0,
    "prefAgeTo" : 0,
    "notificationNewMatch" : true,
    "notificationMessage" : true,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-06-01T04:29:54.325Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-06-01T04:29:54.325Z")
}
```

Now i want to get Authentication token on the basis of user id in authentication collection.

I am using Mongo Repository to fetch AuthenticationToken on the basis of user id but it is not working.

To fetch AuthenticationToken

Step 1

```
public AuthenticationToken findByUserId(String userId){
      ObjectId objId =  new ObjectId(userId);
        return authRepository.findByUserId(objId);
    }
```

Step 2

```
public interface AuthenticationTokenRepository extends MongoRepository<AuthenticationToken, String> {

    AuthenticationToken save(AuthenticationToken token);

    AuthenticationToken findByToken(String token);

    @Query("{'user._id' : ?0}")
    AuthenticationToken findByUserId(ObjectId objId);
}
```

I am following above steps to fetch AuthenticationToken from DB but getting null. Previously it was working fine when i was not using @DBRef over User in Authentication Domain.

AuthenticationToken

```
public class AuthenticationToken extends BaseEntity{

    @JsonProperty
    String token;

    @DBRef
    User user;

    public AuthenticationToken(String token,User user){
        this.token = token;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not big deal,use spring data mongodb criteria like

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("user.$id").is(new ObjectId(userId)));
        AuthenticationToken token = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, AuthenticationToken.class);
```